# Changing color based on categorical variable in ggplot 2 loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to change the color of the line across the plots based on the categorical variable "Colonizers". This is my code:

```
for (i in country_count$Country){ print(
filter(df_period5,Country==i)%>%complete(period5=seq.Date(min(period5), max(period5), by="year"))%>%mutate(n= ifelse(is.na(n), 0,   n))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=period5, y=n, colour='df_period5$Colonizers'))+geom_line(aes(x = period5, y = n, colour = 'df_period5$Colonizers'))+
  ylab("Number of Objects")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif")) +ggtitle(as.character(i)))+ scale_x_continuous( breaks =seq(1900-01-01,2019-01-01))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5000,10))
```

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(period5 = structure(c(-11688, -11688, -7670, -14245, 
-7305, -13149, 7305, -2557, -10592, -14610), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles", class = "Date"), 
    Country = c("cameroun", "tchad", "tchad", "mali", "tchad", 
    "cameroun", "madagascar", "madagascar", "mali", "mali"), 
    n = c(4135L, 2725L, 2479L, 1803L, 1674L, 1264L, 1088L, 1032L, 
    863L, 761L), Independence.x = c(1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.x = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.y = c(1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.y = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.x.x = c(1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.x.x = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.y.y = c(1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.y.y = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence = c(1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have been trying for hours. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and paste the result into your question, this help to solve your issue. Thanks. Without seeing your data, you could try `colour = factor(df_period5$Colonizers)`

Comment: (1) no need to reference `colour=` twice - just use either inside `aes()` for `ggplot()` or `geom_line()`.  (2) don't reference a column name with quotes (single or double) inside `aes()`.  (3) don't use the reference with the dataframe name inside `aes()` - it already references the `data=` dataframe.  All together, reference `colour=` once and use: `colour = Colonizers` (no quotes there).  Does that fix it?   If not, please post a `dput()` and give some more info on how you want your plots to look...

Comment: @chemdork123 Thank you for your response! with the changes you suggested, I get a legend with the appropriate level but the color of the line remains the same.  I added the data on the post.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Thank you for your response, and sorry for being vague. I just added the 10 first lines of the data)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set the color of the line using a character string instead of the actual variable. Try removing the quotes around 'df_period5$Colonizers' in both aes() statements:

```
for (i in country_count$Country){ print(
filter(df_period5,Country==i)%>%complete(period5=seq.Date(min(period5), max(period5), by="year"))%>%mutate(n= ifelse(is.na(n), 0,   n))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=period5, y=n, colour=df_period5$Colonizers))+geom_line()+
  ylab("Number of Objects")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif")) +ggtitle(as.character(i)))+ scale_x_continuous( breaks =seq(1900-01-01,2019-01-01))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5000,10))
```

Also, since you have already specified the x and y aesthetics in the ggplot() call, you don't need to repeat them in geom_line(). Just calling geom_line() should be sufficient. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I made those changes. The code runs with the right legend on each plot but the color of the line is the same across all plots.