# Changing color based on categorical variable in a ggplot loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to change the line color in the plots based on the categorical variable "Colonizers".  The plots display the legend with the appropriate level but the color is the same for all plots.

Here's my data:

```r
structure(list(period5 = structure(c(-11688, -11688, -7670, -14245, 
-7305, -13149, 7305, -2557, -10592, -14610), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles", class = "Date"), 
    Country = c("cameroun", "tchad", "tchad", "mali", "tchad", 
    "cameroun", "madagascar", "madagascar", "mali", "mali"), 
    n = c(4135L, 2725L, 2479L, 1803L, 1674L, 1264L, 1088L, 1032L, 
    863L, 761L), Independence.x = c(1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.x = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.y = c(1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.y = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.x.x = c(1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.x.x = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence.y.y = c(1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers.y.y = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France"), Independence = c(1960, 1960, 
    1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960), Colonizers = c("France", 
    "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "France", "France")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the code:

```
df_period5$period5<-as.Date(df_period5$period5)

for (i in country_count$Country){ print(
filter(df_period5,Country==i)%>%complete(period5=seq.Date(min(period5), max(period5), by="year"))%>%mutate(n= ifelse(is.na(n), 0,   n))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=period5, y=n, color=Colonizers))+geom_line(aes(colour = Colonizers))+
  ylab("Number of Objects")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif")) +ggtitle(as.character(i)))+ scale_x_continuous( breaks =seq(1900-01-01,2019-01-01))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,5000,10)) 
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion as to way this is not working. Thank you!

Comment: Unless you specify which colour to use for which colonizer, ggplot will use default values for each plot. In most cases there will only be one or few colonizers per plot (country), so the first n colors correspond even though colonizer(s) vary. You can match colors to countries like this: `ggplot(...) + ... + scale_color_manual(values = c('France' = 'green', 'Another country' = 'blue', ...))`

Comment: You have already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883433/changing-color-based-on-categorical-variable-in-ggplot-2-loop), please refrain from reposting the same question. It is better to edit your original question.